# Remove minimum number of nodes to make graph disconnected

Tags: graph-theory, network-flow

Find the minimum number of nodes that need to be removed to make graph disconnected( there exists no path from some node x to all other nodes). Number of nodes can be 10<sup>5</sup>

Comment: I am sorry, but what is your graph structure? You should make it clear to get an answer.

Comment: Given a connected undirected graph

Comment: Sorry, this is still unclear. For example, you should display the vertex set $V$ and edge set $E$ of the graph before we can determine the connectivity of it.

Comment: [example](https://pasteboard.co/J3CgENJ.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are searching for the minimum $k$ such that your graph $G = (V, E)$ is $k$-vertex-connected.

To solve this problem consider Menger's theorem:

> Let $G$ be a finite undirected graph and $x$ and $y$ two nonadjacent vertices. Then the size of the minimum vertex cut for $x$ and $y$ (the minimum number of vertices, distinct from $x$ and $y$, whose removal disconnects $x$ and $y$) is equal to the maximum number of pairwise internally vertex-disjoint paths from $x$ to $y$.

(from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menger%27s_theorem))

You can find such paths using a reduction of the vertex-version of Menger's theorem to the edge-version of Menger's theorem, which may be solved in a variety of ways, e.g. by solving a max-flow problem.

$k$ is the minimum over the cardinality of a minimum vertex cut for $(u, v)$ for every pair $(u, v)$ of non-adjacent nodes in $G$.
$$ k = \min \left\{ \text{cardinality of minimum $u$-$v$-cut} \mid (u, v) \in V \times V, u~\text{and}~v~\text{are non-adjacent} \right\} $$